# Does Bruce Banner hang up on Tony Stark?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, thor-marvel, team-thor

I've just seen the [Mocumentary](https://twitter.com/MarvelStudios/status/769927705651392513/video/1) 'Team Thor'.

I couldn't be certain but it looks like Banner hangs up on Tony Stark. Does he?

Comment: B: "He doesn't know how to get in touch with you." T: "I don't have a phone." B:"He doesn't have a phone." T:"Send a raven." (blank stare)

Comment: The video wouldn't play for me at that link. Youtube works: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bPNBKT6JLSU

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**No, he does not.**

The way these phones work, answering or hanging up is determined by the direction you swipe your thumb. If you watch the video clip starting at the appropriate moment:

[image: short animated gif of the relevant scene: we see a close up of a call being connected on a mobile phone, then cut to Banner putting a phone to his ear]

You can clearly see that his thumb presses down on the right hand side and swipes across to the left. That's how you answer these type of phone.

Of course, he then proceeds to talk to Tony for about a minute; the only reason to hang up on him would be so Thor wouldn't see him talking to Tony, so why "pretend" to be talking to him anyway?

Comment: I suspect the phone image was added in post, because usually there's some kind of visual cue that you're swiping, but the thumb motion is at least correct.

Comment: The way it hangs over the hang up then goes left to touch the 'pickup' is what confused me.

Comment: This is how you reject the call.   This answer makes no sense.

Answer (score 2):

**Yes, he does.**

The way these phones work, answering or hanging up is determined by hitting or swiping the appropriate button. If you watch the video clip below:

[image: short animated gif of the relevant scene: we see a close up of a call being disconnected on a mobile phone, then cut to Banner putting a phone to his ear]

You can clearly see that his thumb presses down on the right hand side and swipes across to the left. That's how you hang up this type of phone.

He does this presumably to fake a conversation with Tony Stark, as if he isn't "on Tony's team". The following "conversation" and reluctance in handing the phone over to Thor makes it clear he has in fact hung up.

Comment: I don't know why the other answer is upvoted and accepted.   He is clearly meant to be swiping left to hang up.